# How can application use reflection to use other dll's method which reply on the third dll

Tags: c#, reflection

This is the definition of the DemoImport.dll, which relies on the RestSharp NuGet.

```cs
using RestSharp;

namespace DemoImport;

public class ImportClass
{
    public void JustAMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        var client = new RestClient();
    }
}
```

This is the definition of the DemoClient, which use reflection to use the method "JustAMethod":

```cs
using System.Reflection;

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Demo.dll");
Type? type = assembly.GetType("DemoImport.ImportClass");
object intance = Activator.CreateInstance(type)!;
type.GetMethod("JustAMethod").Invoke(intance,Array.Empty<object>());
```

However, I get error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=109.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75'. System cannot find the target file。
File name: 'RestSharp, Version=109.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75'
   at DemoImport.ImportClass.JustAMethod()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in F:\Program.cs:line 6
```

Comment: Why use reflection in the first place? I would go to some substantial lengths to _avoid_ using reflection.

Comment: Well, where is the restsharp.dll file? I think LoadFile should try to load dependencies from the same folder as you demo.dll file, but I can't remember if you need to do anything extra to make it do so.

Comment: @Fildor Is there another solution to archieve the same thing? I want to implement a plugin load.

Comment: @JonasH . The restsharp is just the NuGet(Restsharp) that I used in the DemoImport.dll.

Comment: If you need to use reflection to use a plugin, then I would suggest to go back to the drawing board and rethink that plugin architecture.

Comment: A nuget is just a convenience wrapper around dlls. So, if you do fancy stuff like lazy loading dlls, then you may have to also consider their dependencies manually.